# What is the proper way to take user input from a text field?

Tags: android, input

I'm trying to make a highscore list in my app and I need the user to be able to input their name after they lose so it can go on the highscore list. How should I do this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#EditText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an EditText and use `String name = edittext.getText().toString();`

**EDIT :**

add  this to your XML layout.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edittext" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```